# How many partial permutations are there for a 4-digit number where no two consecutive numbers are the same?

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations

Q.How many partial permutations are there for a 4-digit number where no two consecutive numbers are the same?

A.7290?

Came across this question and would like to validate my logic or get a more robust answer. Assuming integers range from 0 to 9, we have 4 positions to be filled. 1st position can take 10 digits, 2nd position can only take 9 digits due to our constraint. Subsequently 3rd and 4th positions can also only take 9 possible digits as we cannot repeat any two consecutive numbers.

Therefore we arrive at:
(10 x 9 x 9 x 9) = 7290

Comment: Compare the question of "$4$-digit **strings**" and "$4$-digit **numbers**".  $0123$ is not a $4$-digit *number*, it is only a $3$-digit number.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @saulspatz no, an answer of $10\times 9\times 9\times 9$ is correct only for the question of counting how many $4$-digit strings there are.  It is incorrect for the question of counting how many $4$-digit numbers there are.  In the question of $4$-digit numbers, our first step has only nine options, not the usual ten, since zero is not permitted to be the leading digit.